# Need bg to Fit Text

Tags: css

[On this website](http://glamourunderground.com) as you can see, the white background doesn't fit the text (content)... How can I get it to do so? This is the CSS... But it doesn't seem to be responding:
`.entry {
    margin:0 0;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    width: 680px;
    }`

Thanks - Tara

Comment: Where is the white background defined? Which `div`?

Comment: @pekka I'm not sure... That's kinda the problem. I'm using a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background is an image:

```
background: url(images/single.jpg) repeat-y;
```

background images can't scale.

Remove the background image, and give the `single` class these additional rules:

```
overflow: auto;
background-color: white;
```

Answer (score 0):

The white background that I think you're asking about is actually a 630px wide JPEG image.